# UWP User Control Unable to instatiate MyUserControl

Tags: c#, uwp, user-controls

My Uwp app builds and runs correctly. The User Control is visible in the user control designer. When I initially add the control to my main page the control is visible in  the designer. I run the app and come back to main Page designed and the  User Control has vanished and the xaml says "Unable ti instaiate an object of type user Control. I don;t understand why the control is visible in the user control designer but not the main page designer AND  the app runs fine.

Has anybody else  come across this problem? is there a clue to where I might find issues in the user control?
The XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UI_Test_1.Controls.BookingTimeControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:UI_Test_1.Views"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:telerik="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input"
xmlns:uControls="using:UI_Test_1.Controls"
d:DesignHeight="400"
d:DesignWidth="500"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                            </Style>
                            <Style
                                x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle"
                                BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}"
                                TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="PressedBackground"
                            Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                            Fill="Transparent" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="yellow" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <uControls:StringFormatConverter x:Key="dateFormatter" />


</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Grid
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="Black">



        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Width="445"
            Height="350"
            Margin="5,5,5,5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="Blue"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListBox
                Name="timeSelectionList"
                Width="135"
                Height="350"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="2"
                GotFocus="Control_GotFocus"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle1}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind timeSelectors}"
                LostFocus="Control_LostFocus"
                PreviewKeyDown="timeSelectionList_PreviewKeyDown"
                SelectionChanged="TimeSelectionList_SelectionChanged" />
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
                <DatePicker
                    x:Name="cal"
                    Background="White"
                    Date="{x:Bind viewModel.bookingTime, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DateChanged="cal_DateChanged"
                    DayFormat="{}{day.integer} {dayofweek.abbreviated}"
                    FontSize="20"
                    GotFocus="Control_GotFocus"
                    LostFocus="Control_LostFocus"
                    Opacity="100"
                    PreviewKeyDown="cal_PreviewKeyDown" />

                <TimePicker
                    x:Name="timePicker"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="White"
                    FontSize="20"
                    GotFocus="Control_GotFocus"
                    LostFocus="Control_LostFocus"
                    MinuteIncrement="5"
                    TimeChanged="timePicker_TimeChanged" />


                <TextBox
                    Name="bookingTimeBox"
                    Width="250"
                    Height="auto"
                    Margin="5,0,5,5"
                    Background="Black"
                    FontSize="12"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Foreground="Yellow"
                    Text="{x:Bind viewModel.bookingTime, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource dateFormatter}}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>


        </StackPanel>






    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As you can see  `d:DesignHeight` property in user control, and it used for UI designer, it is not actual property, you may lost detail  in your question such as code and init process please add it, otherwise, we hardly to give an answer based on incomplete information.

Comment: Ok I have added the user control XAML. Not sure where your going with the D:DesignHeight?

Comment: Please check line 11 - 12 in  your xaml code.

Comment: I removed those lines it doesn't make any difference if that is waht your getting at?